# how to launch minecraft server?

Tags: server, wine, minecraft

I recently switched from windows to Ubuntu server to run my minecraft server,  but my server only has a launch command for Windows and Mac. I've been searching for solutions and installed `wine`, but I can't figure out how to run my "launch-server.bat" file. I'm new to Linux so it might be something obvious I just don't know about.

If possible I would like to have the server launching all in one file so I can place that file in the boot folder of my system so the server will startup when I turn my server on; if possible without having to enter the password to login. Does anybody how to do this? I tried launching the server through the command line using:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Can't recognise 'java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
```

I installed java jdk, do I need jre too?

Comment: omg, i for real typed "hot to launch" i obviously meant "how to launch"

Comment: Yes.  JDK = Java Development Kit.  JRE = Java Runtime Environment.  You need JRE to run Java.  You should also re-implement your server for Linux.  Just google for a Linux tutorial and you'll be good to go.

Comment: If you made a mistake... [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/880502/edit) your question.

Comment: I edited the question!

Comment: i tried the command to install the jre but it said java was already installed, detected as the jdk, can't i just install both? 
btw i installed this ubuntu server OS very recently so it lacks alot of things. one of those is a proper installing program, double clicking in file manager opens a .deb file with Xarchiver. so up until now i install everything with LXTerminal, which at least makes me learn some commands